# How to save image in a String path in flutter?

Tags: flutter, file, storage

I upload a picture,and it is a `File` variable.

Now I want to upload it to cloud storage,but it needs filePath as a parameter,how can I save this File,in a path way?

Comment: You can use the "path_provider" package. So you can access the temporary directory and appDir. https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Answer (score 0):

You file probably already has a path.
You may want to use the `.path` getter on the your `File` object.

Check out the official documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/path.html

Comment: I looked up this, but I failed to write.The example shows a `txt` writing example,does image file works well?

Comment: I found the correct filePath in emulator android, it was just a black(and wrong) image,but it had 136B size

Comment: Maybe the way you fetch the image is wrong then ? Or it could be another path